# Top-align content in table cells?

Tags: html

I have a table, two columns. The left column seems to be vertically centered by default. I'd like to top-align all content instead:

```
 ---------------------------
 |           | words words |
 | apples    | words words |
 |           | words words |
 ---------------------------
```

Yeah how can I get the 0th column to top-align its content instead?

```
<table width="100%">
<tr>
  <td>apples</td>
  <td>words words ....</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

> table valign="top" width="100%"

or

> style="vertical-align:top;"

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code:

```
<table width="100%">
<tr>
  <td align="center" valign="top">apples</td>
  <td>words words words words words words words words</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The HTML way is to replace `<tr>` by `<tr valign=top>`. You can use the `valign` attribute on individual cells, too, but not on the entire table (at least by the specs).

The CSS way is to use the `vertical-align` property. For example, to make it apply to all table cells in the document, use

```
<style>
th, td { vertical-align: top; }
</style>
```